# Qt Designer is buggy

Tags: qt, qt5

I installed QT 5.11.0 on Ubuntu 17.10. I launched Qt Designer with `~/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/bin/designer`. However, I cannot maximize the Designer window, I cannot drag and drop widgets, widgets change location in left panel when I click them. In general the Designer feels very buggy. I know people complained about drag&drop issue and mostly they solved their problem by switching to gnome-shell from unity. But in 17.10, gnome is the default. I wonder if I am the only one having these weird issues besides drag&drop.